# How to get Signature hash code of a phone app via adb on pc？

Tags: android, adb, signature

For example, in an android program, I can do it like this:

```
android.content.pm.Signature[] sigs =   pkm.getPackageInfo(
                 "com.test", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
```

But, how can I do it via adb on PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex has a great answer.

**WARNING**: Ugly code ahead

I was able to get the signature in adb shell as root with the following code:

```
package=com.test; b=false; while read line; do case $line in *\<package*${package}*) b=true ;; *\<cert*) if $b; then echo $line | sed -e 's|.*key="||' -e 's|".*||'; b=false; fi esac; done < /data/system/packages.xml
```

indented:

```
package=com.test
b=false
while read line; do
    case $line in 
        *\<package*${package}*)
            b=true ;; 
        *\<cert*)
            if $b; then
                echo $line | sed -e 's|.*key="||' -e 's|".*||'
                b=false
            fi
    esac
done < /data/system/packages.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
service call package 2 s16 "com.test" i32 64
```

and parse the resulting `Parcel` dump